# Sort files by type in Bash

Tags: bash, sorting, find

I have a folder with files of many types.
How can I sort them by file extension, to be left with a folder called "doc" of Word docs, a folder "jpg" with jpgs, etc.

A few caveats:

- The files are currently in subdirectories of various depths. There is no need to maintain the relative paths - a file in unsorted/1995/summer/DCIM should go directly into sorted/jpg.
- It is possible that two files may have the same name. In that case, it must either ignore the second file [an error would be nice], or preferably, append something to the name of the second file while moving (file.jpg -> file_01.jpg)
- As I do not know all the file types, the script should create the folder if one with that name does not exist. (ie. if it hits a file "old.wpd", it should create a folder sorted/wpd.
- I cannot use copy - I need to move the files - as we are dealing with a very large amount of files, and I haven’t got space on the hard drive to duplicate them.

I would prefer a Bash script, as I’m somewhat interested in knowing Bash, but can use Fish or ZSH if need be.

For the sake of my learning, if there was a solution that would maintain the relative paths, I would be curious to know what it is as well.

EDIT:
Am running a Mac, with coreutils installed through Brew.
My failed attempts used find, but I couldn't get the file extension in a usable form.

Comment: Pretty good set of specifications.  It might have been good if you could share your thoughts on how to approach the problem.

Comment: I had this as an interview question once.

Comment: This is perilously close to "please write my code for me". I answered because I think the answer has some tutorial value, but you'll still need to do some work with the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one possible utility function which you could use. It takes a base directory and a path to a file, and moves the file to a uniquely named file in an appropriate subdirectory of the base directory.

For production use, I would recommend extending the function to take a list of filenames rather than a single one.

In any event, you could use the `-exec` option of the `find` command to arrange for the utility to be called on all appropriate files. If you extend the function as recommended, you would want to trigger it with `-exec ... +` rather than `-exec ... {}`. (See `man find` for details.)

Note: I've written this as a function rather than as a script, but `find -exec` can't call bash functions. So you'll need to either wrap the function in a script file, or unwrap it into a script file.

**Important Note:** Also, I just typed this; I didn't verify that it works. As always, scripting large changes to filesystems should only be done in the presence of good backups and after careful testing in a controlled environment.

```
# Usage: ext_move <directory> <file>
ext_move() {
  # Extract the filename from the path
  local base=$(basename $2)
  # Extract the (last) extension from the filename
  local ext=${base##*.}
  # Verify that it is really an extension
  # This test could be much more rigorous (eg. only alphanumerics)
  if [[ $ext = "$base" || $ext = "" ]]; then
    echo "'$2': No extension; not moved"
    return 1
  fi
  # Make sure the subdirectory exists
  if ! mkdir -p "$1/$ext"
    return 1
  fi
  # Try moving the file, but refuse to overwrite an existing file. If
  # this fails, then we need to find a different file name
  if ! mv -n "$2" "$1/$ext/$base" 2>/dev/null; then
    # Strip the extension off the base:
    base=${base%.$ext}
    # We don't try *too* hard here, because the move might fail for other reasons.
    local suf
    for suf in _{01..99}; do
      if mv -n "$2" "$1/$ext/$base$suf.$ext" 2>/dev/null; then
        return
      fi
    done
    # If we get here, we failed 100 different filenames. Maybe
    # there is some other problem. (filesystem full, permissions, etc.)
    # Repeat last move in order to present the error message
    mv -n "$2" "$1/$ext/$base$suf.$ext"
  fi
}
```

A few implementation notes:

1. The function is designed to work atomically in case multiple instances of it are being performed in parallel with different source files, as might be the case if it were triggered with `xargs` rather than `-exec`. So it needs to make sure that the test for the existence of the target filename is atomic, which precludes doing something list `test -f $name` followed by the move. Instead, we simply try doing the move using a technique which will fail if the target name exists. Avoiding "test-before-modify" race conditions is always important in script design.
2. `mv -n` is a Gnu extension which cause the move to fail if the target filename exists. Posix `mv` will just overwrite the file, which is obviously not what we want. If we don't have Gnu `mv`, we could achieve the same effect by using `ln -s` to link the new name to the old file; this will fail if the new name exists, which satisfies the locking requirements, but in that case we'll still need to actually do the move after the link succeeds. While the code is slightly more complicated, it has a couple of advantages: first, it is more portable, and second, it allows for better detection of error conditions. So it's more appropriate for a production script.

Comment: +1: Using the GNU `mv` extension `-n` (`--no-clobber`) is nice, but be aware that it is not part of POSIX so some other systems won't have the feature available.

Comment: +1. good defensive programming.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a short one, assuming you have the GNU coreutils installed.

```
#!/bin/bash

destination=~/Test/pwetpwet

find "$1" -type f -execdir bash -c '
   base=${0#./}
   extension=${base##*.}
   [[ $extension != $base ]] || { echo >&2 "File $PWD/$base skipped: no extension"; exit 0; }
   destdir=$1/${extension,,}
   mkdir -p -- "$destdir" && mv --backup=numbered -- "$0" "$destdir"
' {} "$destination" \;
```

You might want to echo the "dangerous" line:

```
echo mkdir -p -- "$destdir" && echo mv --backup=numbered -- "$0" "$destdir"
```

for testing purposes. The `--backup=numbered` extension to `mv` will, well, create numbered backups instead of overwriting files.

This script only takes one argument (the source folder); you can easily adapt it to take two arguments (source and target).

**I haven't thoroughly tested it, so use at your own risks!**

Comment: Wow. I'm working through understanding this now, but it's short and easier to follow than I expected.

Comment: When a file a.jpg and a.JPG both exist (in subfolders), the latter  overwrites the former instead of incrementing it. I assume that this is because mv assumes a case-sensitive OS, which the Mac is not. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: @SamGoody What? Mac is not case-sensitive for file names? That's dumb `:D`. Then you can try to replace the `mv --backup=numbered -- "$0" "$destdir"` part with `mv --backup=numbered -- "$0" "$destdir/${base,,}"`. This will force the target to have a lowercase base. Let me know if it works, I'll include it in the answer.

Comment: It did not work. But after running a number of tests, I cannot figure out what isn't working. 1) The filename gets changed to lowercase, which I would not like. 2) The latter files are still overwriting the first files sometimes. I put a file in the sorted folder, and two in the orig folder - nothing was overwritten, then put another two in the orig folder and reran it - this time one of the new ones met an untimely death, and the other overwrote the ~2~ file.

Comment: @SamGoody: can you try this (in a scratch directory): `touch file{1..3}; mv -v --backup=numbered file2 file1; mv -v --backup=numbered file3 file1`? (the `v` option to `mv` to be verbose). Can you also provide a minimal example (like I did) that shows the problem you're encountering (with the `-v` option to `mv`)?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

destination=/path/to/destination/folder

find . -type f -depth -print0 |
while read -d '' -r filename; do
    base=$(basename "$filename")
    extension=${base ##*.}
    if [[ $base == $extension ]]; then
        echo "ignoring file with no dot in the name: $filename"
        continue
    fi

    # file.jpg and file.JPG should go to the same new folder
    ext_dir="$destination/$( tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' <<< "$extension")"
    [[ -d "$ext_dir" ]] || mkdir "$ext_dir"

    if [[ -f "$ext_dir/$base" ]]; then
        # file.jpg already exists, find a new name
        base_noext=${base%.*}
        n=0
        while ((n++)); do
            printf -v base "%s_%03d.%s" "$base_noext" $n "$extension"
            [[ -f "$ext_dir/$base" ]] || break
        done
    fi

    if ln "$filename" "$ext_dir/$base"; then
        echo "successfully linked: $filename -> $ext_dir/$base"
        rm "$filename" || echo "could not remove: $filename"
    else
        echo "could not link: $filename -> $ext_dir/$base"
    fi
done
```

Using a hard link (`ln`) means that you don't have to copy the bytes, so this should be pretty efficient, assuming you're moving within the same filesystem.

Comment: `n=0; while ((n++)); ...`: the `while` branch will never get executed.

Comment: `${extension,,}` will expand to lowercased `$extension`, hence rendering the external `tr` useless.